# using cryptsetup in gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have created a docker container to be used in a gitlab-ci pipeline to build a java project. Properties files for an integration test are in an encrypted image I want to mount in the container during the execution of the integration test stage.

In my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt install -y libncurses5-dev
RUN apt install -y cryptsetup
```

The docker image gets built and pushed without problems.

In my Gitlab CI File:

```
mkdir -p configs
echo -n $LUKSOPEN_PASS_PHRASE | /usr/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen configs.img /home/java/config
```

But when the pipeline is run:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ -| echo 'integration tests' mkdir -p /home/java/config mkdir -p configs                cryptsetup echo -n $LUKSOPEN_PASS_PHRASE | /usr/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen configs.img /home/java/config mount /dev/mapper/configs configs cp configs/* /home/java/config ls /home/java/config gradle integrationTest
/usr/bin/bash: line 113: /usr/sbin/cryptsetup: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/bash: line 113: -: command not found
```

When I log into the container, cryptsetup is there:

```
sven@ixori:~/workspace/java-11-container$ docker run -it 9b733f66d757 /bin/bash
root@1193dc1f57b9:/# cryptsetup
Usage: cryptsetup [-?Vvyrq] [-?|--help] [--usage] [-V|--version] [-v|--verbose] [--debug]
        [--debug-json] [-c|--cipher=STRING] [-h|--hash=STRING] [-y|--verify-passphrase]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In your test at the end there, you're relying on `$PATH`, while in your script, you're explicitly calling `/usr/sbin/cryptsetup`. Are you sure it's in `/usr/sbin`?

Comment: Yes, I changed that from the call without full path;
root@ac8981182f2e:/# which cryptsetup
/usr/sbin/cryptsetup
root@ac8981182f2e:/#

Comment: OK, I found the problem. Our GitLab runner uses a cached instance of the container, so the older version without cryptsetup was used.